# How to print with the same font used in the SWT StyledText widget?

Tags: java, printing, swt

When I print the content of the styledtext widget the font is different from the one i have set.

Is there a way to set the font for the `Printer` object?

```
Printer printer = new Printer();
styledText.print(printer).run();
```